# Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and the image exists

Tags: video, youtube, xhtml-1.0-strict, prettyphoto

On my page I have a YouTube video's thumbnail as image, and I want to play the video using **prettyPhoto** after the user clicks on the image. How can I accomplish that?

Here's my code for the image:

```
<div class="video" id="videoPlaceHolder" style="position:relative;">
  <a rel="prettyPhotos" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php getFirstFeatureVideoURL(); ?>">
    <img style="background:url(<?php getFirstFeatureVideoThumbnail() ?>); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;  -moz-background-size: cover;" src="/images/ytIndex_overlay.png" onClick="addPlayer();" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The php function `getFirstFeatureVideoURL` grabs and returns the first video's "correct" URL (I have checked it separately and the video plays w/o any problem). The other function called `getFirstFeatureVideoThumbnail` returns the video's thumbnail. I have all the plugins ready for the `prettyPhoto`, and so far it's working for all the images perfectly. However, when I try to play this video by clicking on the image, it gives me the error:

`Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and the image exists`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up generating the < a > and < img > tags inside my PHP function like below and that fixed my problem....

```
function getFeatureVideo()
{
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/A4F160EDF82713A2?v=2');
.
.
.
.
$media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watch = $attrs['url'];

  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
  $thumbnail = $attrs['url'];

  $result .='<a rel="prettyVideos"  href="'.$watch.'">
                <img style="background:url('.$thumbnail.'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;  -moz-background-size: cover;" src="/images/ytIndex_overlay.png" onClick="addPlayer();" />
       </a> ';      

echo $result;                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects the `href` to be a URL. You can't embed PHP code in a URL like that.

Comment: but the *href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php getFirstFeatureVideoURL(); ?>"* is retunring me a valid link..."https://www.youtube.com/embed/Id_kGL3M5Cg"

Answer (score 0):

What is the thumbnail version you are trying to get. I guess you try to retrieve Standard Definition Thumbnail or Maximum Resolution Thumbnail. Both of them does not exist for this video id: Id_kGL3M5Cg

Use this tool to check of it exist or not: [YouTube video info generator](http://www.techtweaker.com/tool/youtube-video-information-generator/?v=Id_kGL3M5Cg)

I got the result,
Standard Definition Thumbnail is not available for this video.
Maximum Resolution Thumbnail is not available for this video.

You can check if image exist or not using `get_headers`. Check the thumbnail section of the code in this tutorial: [How to get YouTube Video Info with PHP](http://www.techtweaker.com/how-to-get-youtube-video-info-with-php/)